# Azure smartcard auth

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, smartcard

I am trying to understand how smartcard auth happens over Azure. I Understand that we require on-Prem ADFS however I am trying figure out two things:

**1)** What exact exchange takes places between Azure and client? Something like below:

> GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
>   client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
>   &response_type=id_token+code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3a12345
>   &response_mode=form_post&scope=openid&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F&state=12345&nonce=678910

**2)** How is Smartcard Authenticated? Is it a challenge response or the certificate is verified? In case of challenge response the client generates a signed data that is verified by ADFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1)What exact exchange takes places between Azure and client?

The sample request you mentioned is a sign-in request to [get access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#get-access-tokens), for the exact exchange between Azure and client, just refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#oauth-20-authorization-flow).

[image]

> 2) How is Smartcard Authenticated? Is it a challenge response or the certificate is verified? In case of challenge response the client generates a signed data that is verified by ADFS?

I think it may be a challenge response, and the client will generate a signed data that is verified by ADFS.

You could refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-now-supports-federation-with-windows-server-active-directory/), as mentioned in the **How federated access works with Windows Azure (Step 4)** :

> The KDC issues the client a Service Ticket, containing the multifactor claims (this assumes that IT policy forced smartcard authentication at desktop login time, otherwise, **AD FS can challenge to present a smartcard** during this Windows Azure Management Portal login sequence).
>
> **The client PC presents the Service Ticket to AD FS.  AD FS validates the Kerberos ticket and generates a signed SAML token for Windows Azure AD in the next step.**  AD FS will only send the signed SAML token if the credentials are valid.

Comment: thanx that was a helpful article.  For question 1 though do you know what the exact request would be or is there a sample software that authenticates against azure using SC?  For exampe here's the exact request for password auth is as follows:

Comment: https://login.microsoftonline.com/resource=ClientRes&client_id=ClientID&grant_type=password&username=UserN&password=PWD&scope=openid

Comment: @M.A I am not sure, I recommend you to ask for the more details about SC in another post, it will be more clear.

Comment: How do i do that?